PowerShell pscustomobject with inputs of varying number of values
I haven't figured out how to ask this question in a way to get the answer on my own. I am dealing with multiple data sources that I am trying to pull specific pieces of data from. List A ($invantroy) will have a 100% response rate, but only holds 2 of the data points. List B (.\facts*) has many more data points but not a 100% response rate. When the first item added to the pscustomobject is found is List B, all my data points are in the final object. However, if the first item in the list is only in list A, then my final object only contains the two data points found in that list. How do write my code to avoid this issue?
$list = Get-Content .\list.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$invantory = $list._meta.hostvars | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

$data=@()
foreach ($server in $invantory.Name){
    if (Test-Path -Path .\facts\$server -PathType Leaf){
        $myJson = Get-Content .\facts\$server -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        $data += [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $server
            PatchTime = ($list._meta.hostvars.($server)).patchtime            
            OSname = "$($myJson.ansible_distribution_file_variety) $($myJson.ansible_distribution_major_version)"
            ServerType = $myJson.ansible_system
            DNSdomain = $myJson.ansible_domain
            PysicalMemory   = $myJson.ansible_memtotal_mb
            PageFileSize = $myJson.ansible_swaptotal_mb
            TotalCPUcoreCount = $myJson.ansible_processor_vcpus
            Sockets = $myJson.ansible_processor_count
            CoresPerSockets = $myJson.ansible_processor_cores
            HyperthreadingEnabled = $myJson.ansible_processor_threads_per_core
            System = $myJson.ansible_env.SAIDKEY
            VolumeName = $myJson.ansible_mounts.mount
            VolumeCapacity = $myJson.ansible_mounts.size_total
            IPaddress = $myJson.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
        }       
    }
    else {
        $data += [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $server
            Patchtime = ($list._meta.hostvars.($server)).patchtime
        }
    }
}


In the else block you should produce an object with the same properties as in the if block and set all non-available properties to either $null or 'N/A'. Also, avoid using += adding to an array as this is very time and memory consuming, plus there is absolutely no need to do so..

I feel like something is not right with $invantory = $list._meta.hostvars | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty  Why are you using Get-Member here?

@Theo that works for the moment. What would you suggest as a better way to add items to the array?
@Daniel I'm not sure I know why other than a google search said that was a way to break out the block of data that was coming from the json so that a foreach would actually work.
